# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_id'

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I Have Created A CallBack Function In Python-Telegram-Bot Wrapper.

```
def add2(update: Updater, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query  
    # add()
    query2 = link1
    _mirror(bot, update, query2)
    query.answer()
```

But I Am Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' objcet Has No Attribute 'Message_id'

```
2022-04-12 06:37:46,195 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 343, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 117, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "/usr/src/app/bot/modules/mirror.py", line 266, in add2
    _mirror(bot, update, query2)
  File "/usr/src/app/bot/modules/mirror.py", line 228, in _mirror
    listener = MirrorListener(bot, update,isTar, tag, extract)
  File "/usr/src/app/bot/modules/mirror.py", line 39, in __init__
    super().__init__(bot, update)
  File "/usr/src/app/bot/helper/mirror_utils/status_utils/listeners.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.uid = self.message.message_id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message_id'
```

Below Is The Link Of _mirror function:
https://github.com/lzzy12/python-aria-mirror-bot/blob/master/bot/modules/mirror.py

Comment: Your message object is None. Debug your code to figure out why you try to call a property on a None-type object. Most likely you should wrap the code that fetches it in a try-except clause and do something (like throw an error) when you can't fetch the message instead of trying to access it's properties before checking if it's not None.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0):

the `_mirror` function passes the `update` to `MirrorListener` which apparently assumes that `update.message` is not `None`. but the `add2` callback is apparently used as callback for a `CallbackQueryHandler`, since you access `update.callback_query`.

Comment: So What Should I Change in add2?